# Chain rule question (Differential cancelling)

Tags: calculus

Why is the following equation true? Given: $x’=x+vt$. 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x’} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x’}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial x’}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$.
Wouldn’t this imply that 1=2, if one can cancel the differentials (e.g. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$)?

Comment: You can't cancel the differentials, though. They're not numbers, they are just a piece of notation.

Comment: Interesting. Cancelling would work if there was only one term on the right side. I guess I just have to be careful with differentials.

Comment: I have the same question. If we can't cancel the differentials then why do we have $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$? Is there any intuitive way to understand this?

Comment: It is possible that the derivative on the left is a ‘total derivative’

Comment: A distinction between a derivative and a total derivative is needed when there is more than one dependent variable, as in the question

Comment: I'm confused by the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}$. Is there an alternate notation? Anyway, the question about the differentials cancelling and $1=2$ is addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109118/why-differentials-can-cancel-in-some-versions-of-chain-rule-but-not-others?r=SearchResults&s=1|80.2382